# Warning on mutable Java variables in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, functional-programming

I'm interested in moving toward more functional constructs in Java, and was wondering if there was a way in Eclipse to have it warn if I have mutable local variables, parameters, class members, etc.  That way, I could gently migrate code as I'm refactoring, and be nudged in that direction as I write new code as well.

I realize that's not all there is to FP, but would at least be a start.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a wild hair over Xmas vacation, and decided to play with a parser, to be able to get a list of places that could benefit from `final`.  Found javaparser.org, and got the following code running as a simple start, that I hope to build on, going forward:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.DirectoryFileFilter;
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.RegexFileFilter;

import com.github.javaparser.JavaParser;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.CompilationUnit;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.Modifier;
import com.github.javaparser.ast.body.FieldDeclaration;

public class JavaFPMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JavaFPMain fpApp = new JavaFPMain();
        fpApp.run();
    }

    private void run() throws Exception {
        File projectDir = new File(...);
        FileUtils.listFiles(projectDir, new RegexFileFilter(".*.java"), DirectoryFileFilter.DIRECTORY)
            .stream()
            .forEach(this::parseFile);

        System.out.println("done");
    }

    private void parseFile(final File fi) {
        try {
            CompilationUnit compilationUnit = JavaParser.parse(fi);

            String AUTOWIRED = "Autowired";
            compilationUnit.getNodesByType(FieldDeclaration.class).stream()
                .filter(f -> !f.getModifiers().contains(Modifier.FINAL) &&
                             !containsAnnotation(f, AUTOWIRED))
                .forEach(f -> System.out.println("missing final: " + fi.getAbsolutePath() + "(" + f.getBegin().get().line + ") " + f.getVariable(0).getNameAsString()));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
        }
    }

    private boolean containsAnnotation(FieldDeclaration f, String name) {
        return f.getAnnotations()
                .stream()
                .anyMatch(a -> a.getNameAsString().equals(name));
    }

}
```

And yes, I get just short of 6,000 lines of output from this, which means that I have my work cut out for me, should I choose to pursue this.  And that's not including parameters that should be made `final`, objects that are still modifiable, etc.  But again, it's a place to start.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, you can get fairly far with the `final` declaration, regardless of your IDE.

```
public class ImmutableThing {
  private final int someInt;
  private final String aString;
}
```

The idea here is that you set these once in the constructor, say, and then never touch them again. (You could provide setter methods, which are more clear, but convey the unwanted notion that this object is mutable.) Eclipse, IntelliJ, etc. should notice the `final` declaration and naturally tell you when you have code trying to muck with these things when it shouldn't. (I forget whether they will tell you if you've declared a final instance variable and provided no way to set it.)

One curveball to watch out for will of course be objects whose fields can be changed without changing the value of the field in your `ImmutableThing`:

```
    private final List<String> strs; // Hmm.
```

You can set up the `strs` in the constructor as above, but that `List`'s contents can of course be changed, so that's no good. In general, any mutable object inside an object you want to be immutable will have this problem. You can get around this in the case of `Collections` (probably the most common mutable objects) by using *unmodifiable* collections:

```
    strs = Collections.unmodifiableList<String>(initList);
```

or by using third-party versions, such as from Guava:

```
    strs = ImmutableList<String>.of ("x", "y", "z");
```

Other objects might provide immutability features; they might not. This feature availability will likely shape how far you get with this paradigm. Generally speaking, you can get pretty far with immutable data objects, and not very far with innately stateful things like streams and connection pools.

Comment: Thanks, yes, but I'm looking to know where I still need to add final, unmodifiableList, etc.

Comment: Hmm. The snippets I gave above were intended as examples. So, if you wanted something to be immutable, you'd make it look like `ImmutableThing` above. Declaring all its fields as `final`. Assuming that doesn't help - could you give more info of something specific you're trying to do, perhaps?

Comment: Well, my original question was if Eclipse could be made to give a warning in such cases.  Give an indication of where things are mutable.  Sure, I can examine my code by hand, but I've got 30-mumble years of imperative habits that are sure to trip me up along the way.  Your examples are exactly what I want to do; I would just like some assistance in spotting where it would go.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand a little better where you're coming from. To answer your first question, in Java, everything not final is mutable, meaning most of any Java code you run across will contain member fields that are virtually all mutable. However, access rules have an effect (i.e. public, private, protected, default). Meaning a lot of those fields are *effectively* immutable, which I would guess complicates your goal of seeing what's mutable at a glance in existing code.

Comment: As I implied in the answer, Eclipse won't really tell you what's mutable, since in practice, nearly everything tends to be, and you'd drown in the signal. From what I think is your perspective, you could just start locking object fields down with `final` and `private` if you think they should be immutable. Then lock down mutator methods (i.e. `setSomething()`) with `private`. If the code has been naughty about changing fields, Eclipse *will* start giving you warnings that it's trying to change a field you'd declared `final` or `private`. Maybe that helps you?

Comment: Of course, supposing you do this for a long while, to the point where nearly everything in your code is locked down... *then* it makes sense for Eclipse to tell you what's left. Maybe that's the thrust of your query. In that light, it's kinda rough to search for what's non-private, non-final, etc... I know there's a long list of settings for what to generate compiler warnings for (search Eclipse's settings for "compiler warnings", in fact), that might have what you're seeking at that point.

Comment: Agreed, I would drown in the noise.  But when I inherited the codebase I'm currently supporting, it had well over a thousand warnings, and over time I fixed those, so... :).  And yes, I have looked through the compiler warnings, and didn't find anything, but wasn't sure if I hadn't overlooked something not so obvious.  Thanks for your time and thought on this.